# evince does not show font names in PDF files anymore

Tags: pdf, evince

```
$ pacman -Q evince
evince 41.4-1
```

Evince does not show font names in PDF files anymore. They look alright, they seem to be embedded normally and the font tab says as much (see screenshot, although it is in my OS' language) but no font name is shown.

This problem occurs regardless of the file's age or producer/origin.

[image]

[image]

Why does that happen?